# Python Pandas Pivot w/o Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to do a Pandas Pivot without using the existing indexes.

I want to take an input like this...

```
  Group  Outstanding Balance
0    AA              4738.32
1    AB              4902.86
2    AC              4850.74
3    AD              7054.80
4    AE              4833.70
5    AF              4199.06
6    AG              4855.80
7    AH              6520.41
```

And turn it into this

```
0       AA       AB       AC      AD      AE       AF      AG       AH
1     4738.32  4902.86  4850.74  7054.8  4833.7  4199.06  4855.8  6520.41
```

I'm then going to iterate through the values and add new rows underneath.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `df.set_index("Group").T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set_index` to move column `Group` to index and simple transpose your dataframe to invert columns and rows:

```
>>> df.set_index('Group').T

Group                     AA       AB       AC      AD      AE       AF      AG       AH
Outstanding Balance  4738.32  4902.86  4850.74  7054.8  4833.7  4199.06  4855.8  6520.41
```

To get exactly your output:

```
>>> df.set_index('Group').T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)

        AA       AB       AC      AD      AE       AF      AG       AH
0  4738.32  4902.86  4850.74  7054.8  4833.7  4199.06  4855.8  6520.41
```

Comment: While I won't/didn't DV this answer, others often DV answers to poorly presented questions. Also, questions such as this are typically DVed, closed, and deleted. As such you're wasting your time. SO is not here to answer every question, it is here to create a repository of **good** questions and answers, which can be used as a resource by others. If the quality of a question can be improved by editing, do so, otherwise it's advised to DV and vote to close.

Comment: This looks like it works. I thought DataFrames were mutable, but it looks like I have to put it in a new DataFrame.

graph_df = df_2.set_index('Group').T.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: @kurt that main reason is really the quality of the question. While you may have tried to solve it, the question itself shows no effort. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and show your effort. Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current & expected output**

Comment: I'm not really agree with that. No matter, the question is short and the answer is fast to write. He doesn't ask to solve a complex problem.

Comment: For those that are still truly curious, this DataFrame represents a subset of a larger DataFrame which contains information about various student loans. The Group column represents the name of the loan accompanied by the current outstanding balance.

The code which Corralien supplied worked for my use case, being; to initiate a new DataFrame, where the index represents the number of months required to payoff the loans, and the columns represent each loan group.

Comment: I then plan to apply calculations to each individual outstanding balance, and then append new rows which represent the new balance, and the total number of rows represents the total number of months required to pay off all the loans. Then I want to graph the values with numpy.  Not sure if this is the best approach, but this is a personal project for myself to learn more about Python and data science.